# MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed : the previous solution needs improvement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-query

I understand that removing the **client.close()** solves the issue but I need to close the connection after the function is done... I can't leave connections open to the database... I don't think it is secure... But every time I do a request... It's okay at first the write completes but once I do it a second time I get the error... yet I do the connect function in the try then the close function in the finally section which means either closing the connection after writing the first time closes the connection permanently or the previously read suggestions that the close is done before the write which I highly doubt since the first write completes successfully... I need some advice

```js
async function Connecting() {
            try {
                await client.connect();
                await createListing(client, req.body, req.query.dbname);
                await res.send("written to " + req.query.dbname);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
                res.send("unable to write due to " + `${e}`);
            } finally {
                await client.close();
                console.log("connection closed");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think making the function not to be async should help since I think close is being called before the database transaction finishes